# Why is the expected parameter to std::atomic::compare_exchange_xxx() not const &?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, atomic

I'm sure I'm about to have a face-palm moment, but here goes:

The prototype for `std::atomic::compare_expected_*` is

```
bool compare_exchange_strong (T& expected, T val,
       memory_order sync = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept;
```

Why is `expected` not a `const T &`?

```
static const handle_t INVALID_HANDLE = 0;
...
std::atomic<handle_t> handle(INVALID_HANDLE);
...
handle.compare_exchange_strong(INVALID_HANDLE, newValue);
```

Surely the exchange methods don't need to modify the expected value?

Comment: If the atomic didn't match `expected`, it copies the current value in there, so you can inspect it in your current thread.

Comment: because `T& expected` will be modified, if compare_exchange failed. here will be stored new value. so this can not be const memory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: Because if the expected parameter were a `const` reference, then `compare_exchange` wouldn't be able to modify it when the exchange fails.

---

You provide both the *expected* and *desired* value to `compare_exchange`.
It modifies your expected value if it founds a different value than the one you provided. In this case, the expected value is not replaced by the desired one that you provided (i.e., it failed to exchange, so you may want to try to exchange the value again).

Usually, you want to use these functions in a loop, for that reason modifying the expected value you provided makes sense, since it provides you with an *updated* version of the expected value.

Consider the following atomic:

```
std::atomic<int> a = 7;
```

and you want to double the value of `a`:

```
int expected = a.load(), desired;
do {
  desired = 2 * expected;
} while (!a.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired));
```

In the code above, if `a` is changed by another thread before the exchange takes place, `expected` is updated by `compare_exchange` with the value of `a` at the moment of trying to perform the exchange (i.e., at the moment of failing).

Otherwise, if `expected` were not modified by `compare_exchange` in case of failure, you would have to load the value of `a` on each iteration of the loop to update `expected`:

```
int expected, desired;
do {
  expected = a.load(); // <-- load on each iteration
  desired = 2 * expected;
} while (!a.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired));
```

Comment: The loop being to make several attempts to set this, making sure another thread hasn't changed the atomic since you last saw it.

Answer (score 3):

It modifies `expected` on failure.

Answer (score 2):

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange):

> Atomically compares the object representation of `*this` with that of `expected`, and if those are bitwise-equal, replaces the former with desired (performs read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, **loads the actual value stored in `*this` into `expected`** (performs load operation).